# R: unique column values, combine rows of second column

Tags: r, dplyr

From a data frame I need a list of all unique values of one column. For possible later check we need to keep information from a second column, though for simplicity combined.

```
Sample data

df <- data.frame(id=c(1,3,1),source =c("x","y","z"))

df
  id    source
1  1         x
2  3         y
3  1         z
```

The desired outcome is

```
df2
      id      source
    1  1         x,z
    2  3         y
```

It should be pretty easy, still I cannot find the proper function / grammar?

E.g. something like

```
df %>%
+     group_by(id) %>%
+     summarise(vlist = paste0(source, collapse = ","))
```

or

```
df %>%
+     distinct(id) %>%
+     summarise(vlist = paste0(source, collapse = ","))
```

What am I missing? Thanks for any advice!

Comment: What is wrong with the 1st attempt - `df %>% group_by(id) %>%  summarise(vlist = paste0(source, collapse = ","))` ? It gives the expected output for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `aggregate` from *stats* to combine per group.

```
aggregate(source ~ id, df, paste, collapse = ",")
#  id source
#1  1    x,z
#2  3      y
```

Comment: for years I have admired your superb base R solutions. I know this isn't your best but I have always regretted not expressing it. You are, in my opinion, the most under-rated R programmer.

Answer (score 1):

Using your code here is a solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(id=c(1,3,1),source =c("x","y","z"))

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(vlist = paste0(source, collapse = ",")) %>% 
  distinct(id, .keep_all = TRUE)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
     id vlist
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 x,z  
2     3 y
```

Your second approach doesn't work because you call `distinct` before you aggregate the data. Also, you need to use `.keep_all = TRUE` to also keep the other column.

Your first approach was missing the `distinct`.

Comment: Ah - excellent - it is a combination of both trials. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It works fine with 'id' being numeric. But this solution does not work anymore, if 'id' is an 'character'. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

```
aggregate(source ~ id, df, toString)
```

Comment: I would also have used `toString` but this collapses with `, ` and not as wanted in the question with `,`.

Comment: @GKi correct, thought I'd demonstrate regardless. Hope you and yours and well and happy in these terrible times. Thanks for teaching me more than any of my comp sci teachers combined.